# Simple mod rewrite question

Tags: mod-rewrite

Here is my current .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi [QSA,L]
```

As you can see, requests to http://domain.com go to http://domain.com/index.html.  I want to change this so that they go to http://domain.com/foo, please note that does not exist as a file or folder, it is handled by rails.  How do I do this?  Note that I have tried the following and it doesn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^$ foo [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi [QSA,L]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're probably safe to just change the first line to this:

```
RewriteRule ^$ foo [QSA,L]
```

The `L` flag tells mod-rewrite that it shouldn't apply any other rules after that one. The problem right now is that the second rule gets applied after the first one, and you end up at "foo.html", instead of "foo", right?

The difference between you trying to send to "foo" and the original redirect to "index.html" is that the second rule applies to requests that do not include a period. So when the first rule was redirecting to "index.html", after it was used, the second rule was no longer valid. However, now that you're not redirecting to a location with a period in it, the second rule gets applied after the first one, so you get a double-redirect.

In addition, you may be able to drop the `QSA` flag from the first line, it depends on your site though. If someone accesses the site like `http://domain.com/?user=fred`, do you want to send them to `http://domain.com/foo?user=fred`, or just `http://domain.com/foo`? If you don't need the **Q**uery **S**tring **A**ppended, you can drop the `QSA` flag, and just have:

```
RewriteRule ^$ foo [L]
```

Comment: The problem with L is that the last line doesn't execute, so it doesn't go to rails (I'm using fastcgi).  I even tried your suggestion (without the L) and removed the second line and it still didn't work.