# How to point my home page traffic to my a Rails subdir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mod-rewrite

I have a rails controller handling requests to www.mydomain/foo, now I want all traffic to www.mydomain/ (the domain root or homepage) to go to www.mydomain/foo.  I asked a similiar question about how to do this with [ReWrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704284/simple-mod-rewrite-question), and haven't gotten an answer yet, but I would be happy also solving it in the controller so I have opened up this questrion to allow for either solution.  Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [map.root](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Routing.html)

What you pass for the options will depend on your controller/actions setup.

Edit - don't forget to delete the index.html file from the /public directory.

Comment: That is exactly what I need, works like a charm.  Thanks, I've been banging my head against the wall on this stupid thing.

Comment: glad my own pain in learning rails could be helpful to someone else :)